# NotFoundException decoding PDF 417

Tags: java, barcode, zxing, pdf417

I use ZXing 3.3.1 library in a Java project to read PDF 417 from images file (scanned from paper and saved as jpg, jpeg).

The library works well for some files, and badly for as many files.

The configuration I use:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private BarCodeReader(){
    BarCodeReader.HINTS = new HashMap();
    BarCodeReader.HINTS.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION,  ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
    BarCodeReader.HINTS.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, true);
    List<BarcodeFormat> possibleFormats = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
    possibleFormats.add(BarcodeFormat.PDF_417);
    BarCodeReader.HINTS.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, possibleFormats);
}
```

How I try to read the file:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public String readBarcode(String filePath) {
    BarCodeResult result = null;
    String errorMessage = "";
    String readMessage = "";
    FileInputStream resizedInput = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    boolean error = false; 
    boolean resized = false;

    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis);

        if (image.getHeight() > MAX_HEIGHT || image.getWidth() > MAX_WIDTH){
            resizedInput = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            image = resizeImage(ImageIO.read(resizedInput), MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);
            resized = true;
        }
        BufferedImageLuminanceSource luminanceSource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
        HybridBinarizer binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(luminanceSource);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
        Result decodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap, HINTS);
        readMessage = decodeResult.getText();

        result = new BarCodeResult(error, readMessage, resized, errorMessage, filePath);
    } catch (Throwable e){
        error = true;
        errorMessage = e.getClass().getName();
    }

    if(fis!=null){
        closeInput(fis, resizedInput);
    }

    if(result != null){
        return result.toJsonString();
    } else {
        return errorJsonString("Unable to get barcode. Null result.");
    }

}
```

Example of image where PDF 417 barcode is not found.
[image]

There is another configuration parameter to optimize the library?